# Dashes between credit card input using bootstrap grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control card-input" maxlength="4" id="creditCardEntry1" placeholder="xxxx">
        </div>  
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group">
             <input type="text" class="form-control card-input" maxlength="4" id="creditCardEntry2" placeholder="xxxx">
        </div>  
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group">
             <input type="text" class="form-control card-input" maxlength="4" id="creditCardEntry3" placeholder="xxxx">
        </div>  
    </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group">
             <input type="text" class="form-control card-input" maxlength="4" id="creditCardEntry4" placeholder="xxxx">
        </div>  
  </div>
```

Which looks good but my client wants a - between the first, second and third text field and I cant figure out how to do it using bootstrap which keeps its responsiveness.

Like this:

[     ] - [     ] - [      ] - [     ]

I've tried imputing a - at the end of the input but it doesn't work at all. It looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxKCD.jpg

All the class `card-input` does it `text-align:center`

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/WTqzS0sAwB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this quick tip ([here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wLqvh68t/))

```
.col-xs-3 + .col-xs-3:before {
    content: "-";
    position: absolute;
    left: -2%;
    top: 6px;
}
```

It's better to create a specific class and don't use `.col-xs-3` in your selector

Comment: Thank you kindly!!

If I were to use a selector, could I use the card-input one I have?
`.card-input + .card-input:before { ... }`

Comment: @user2901304 nope, it must be a class on the same element with the `.col-xs-3`. The `+` selector is for brother selection, the `.card-input` elements are not browser between them